# Adding fuction to edit numbers on diagonal in 2d array

Tags: c

I have a problem with making function to find a number in 2D array to edit numbers in main diagonal to 1 and add this number to all numbers in the line. Like 2D array is:

```
3 5 7
2 6 2
0 9 2
```

and the function should do this:

```
 1 3  5
-3 1 -3
-1 8  1
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define R 4 // pocet riadkov v matici
#define S 4 // pocet stlpcov v matici

void scan(int a[][S]);
void print(int a[][S]);

int main() {
     int a[R][S];
     printf("Vypln maticu (%d X %d) s cislami: \n", R, S);
     scan(a);
     print(a);
     return 0;
}

void scan(int a[][S]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < S; ++j)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
}

void print(int a[][S]) {
    int i, j;
    printf("2D pole: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < S; ++j)
            printf("%3d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want you program to do when given input "ABC"?  You *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following modification to the print function:

```
void print(int a[][S])
{
     int i, j;
     printf("2D pole: \n");
     for (i = 0; i < R; ++i)
     {
          int diagonal_val = a[i][i];
          int alteration_val = 1 - diagonal_val;
          for (j = 0; j < S; ++j)
               printf("%3d ", a[i][j] + alteration_val);
          printf("\n");
     }
}
```

As you know the value of the diagonal is located at a coordinate where i = j (i.e. the row and column numbers are the same). Therefore you can obtain the diagonal value simply by extracting a[i][i], subtracting this from 1 will give you the value you need for changing the value of the other elements. You can simply add the obtained value to each element for the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work properly to read and output the matrix, provided the input is valid.

To modify the matrix you should just subtract the same value from all elements in each row, this value is simply `D-1` where `D` is the value of the cell in the diagonal.

Here is a function that does that:

```
void modify(int a[][S]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        int D = a[i][i] - 1;
        for (j = 0; j < S; ++j)
            a[i][j] -= D;
    }
}
```